# What abstraction level should the servo transitions have?

Tags: c++, arduino, transition

I think I'm using too many methods because of a poor abstraction design. That's why I'm asking this question, different than [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/47515/71839) and similar ones, which only focus on the number of methods per se.

Long story short, I'm doing an Hexapod. I'm saying it because there are some unusual design considerations: you cannot change from going forward to going backwards in no time; so there's some transition time. Also, there's idle time, that's when there's no action.

I'm refactoring my code, but to achieve this I find I'm creating many methods that should not be in the top-level abstraction, but below:

```
void loop()
  {
  // Potentiometer
  String action = Controller.action();
  Serial.println(action);

  // Set the spider to the forward start position
  if (action == "toForward")
    {
    Spidey.toForward();
    }

  // Move the spider forward
  else if (action == "forward")
    {
    Spidey.forward();
    }

  // Get it to standby position
  else if (action == "fromForward")
    {
    Spidey.fromForward();
    }

  // MANY MORE METHODS HERE

  // Default action (stand by)
  else
    {
    Spidey.idle();
    }

  delay(10);
  }
```

In this level, only the `Spidey.forward();` method should be visible, not the transition ones. **How to set the abstraction level for the transition actions?**

My options:

1. Make the `Controller` return another parameter, the "transition", that would be passed to the method being called. Problem: this over-complicates the code.
2. Instead of making the Controller return `toForward`, `forward` and `fromForward`, make it return only `forward`, and then make `Spidey` to handle things internally (store the variable `lastAction` inside `Spidey` instead of storing it insde `Controller` as I'm doing now). Problem: this creates many more private methods, however this is okay according to [the question linked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47515/is-there-such-a-thing-as-having-too-many-private-functions-methods).
3. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on what's happening in Controller now.  Somewhere there needs to be a class keeps a record of the present state and handles the transition sequencing, and translates a request for "forward" to a sequence that transitions the intermediate states.  Maybe this is Controller, or maybe it is Spidey.

To me, it looks wrong to have that big if block to call different functions based on a lot of different magic strings.  That looks more like a very top-level representation that doesn't handle intermediate states.  The internal state transition logic would appear more comfortable using an enumeration. There may then be a member function toState() which would sequence the states to reach that state.

Bear in mind that this class is going to need to be polled or notified when an intermediate state is finished so it can start the next.  If only Controller knows about this, then it may make sense to have that logic there.  Don't try to duplicate or split that logic between two classes.

Comment: Controller is a potentiometer in this case, but it could be anything (radio module, accelerometer, etc).

Comment: I wouldn't mix potentiometer position decoding logic with the state logic, so the intermediate states would be entirely handled by Spidey.  Spidey.setState(targetState) would compare presentState to targetState, and if they are different, then implement the transition state.  It would also check if a transition state has completed, and if so, advance the presentState.